# What data structure to use where keys exist in blocks with gaps between blocks?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have to store data where the key, an integer, follows a pattern like this:

1, 2, 4, 5, 60, 61, 63

That is, keys are sometimes clumped in blocks of hundreds of keys with few gaps in them, but there can be large gaps between blocks. Occasionally there are lone keys or small blocks in the middle of nowhere.

At the moment, `std::map` is used to store the keys, but it is showing up in profiling as taking time to find the keys. This is because we need random-access of keys and there are thousands of keys.

So far the maximum key is 16-bit, so I tried replacing with `std::vector` and it sped up by about 10% in debug mode (whole program performance). Release mode was negligible change, but we do a lot of long work in debug mode.

But now keys may be up to 32-bit in length, so this is not possible.

I tried `std::unordered_map` but this gave worse performance than `std::map`! I don't have much experience with hash maps, so maybe I could tweak the hash policy but I don't know how.

Any suggestions on an efficient data structure for this task?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm honestly somewhat surprised your `std:::unordered_map<>` suffered from the performance issues you're stating. A distribution analysis of your keys may well be warranted to see if you can tune a hash value algorithm that better distributes your data. There is no silver bullet in most key-based algorithms, but I'm... surprised... that `std::map<>` outperforms `std::unordered_map<>`.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector_sparse.htm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer you not from programming side, but from math side.

Maybe it will be good solution (everything depends on real data you have to work with) to create heap analyzer, that will split your thousands of numbers to hundreds of heaps.

Keep in mind lowest heap number as "heap base". 
For each heap you can create vector of pointers to your data, where N element will have number "heap base" + N (so, some of pointers will be nullptr, but such vectors will not be long).

And then you can create map of "heap base" numbers (each connected with it's heap-vector). Accessing N element from vector takes O(1), it have to be very fast. Searching in map your heap - will be also faster, because you will search in hundreds of heaps, not in thousands of numbers.

Using "lower_bound" you will be able to find closest heap to number you are searching, and then search it in that heap.

If your medium heap consist of K numbers, you will increase your speed as Log(2) K. For K = 8 - triple times. You will lose time for searching and some other actions, but may seriously win in speed.

If you need to create that data store just once, and then work with it, it can be solution.

With numbers from your example, you have to receive:
(where T is your objects you are searching)

```
vector<T*> a = {obj1, obj2, nullptr, obj4, obj5}
vector<T*> b = {obj60, obj61, nullptr, obj63}
map<int, vector<T*> > mymap;

mymap.append(pair(1, a));
mymap.append(pair(60, b));
```

(where objN is T*)
and then search for Number, for example 63 using bounds methods. Get vector, and take from it element with number 63-"base" (i.e. with number 3)

Comment: You can create heaps by rule (numbers not far then N). And then test heap creation with N = 2, 4, 6, 10, 20, 100. Look at count of heaps you got and how many heaps consist of one element/elements less then M (the best N will be when you will have as many heaps as possible with as less heaps consists of element less then M as possible).
After you will find that N, you can use it for all time, even if every program start you receive different numbers, they comes by same rule and N you chose from such analysis have to be good enough).

Answer (score 2):

If the keys are more or less constantly spread (on large scales) you can invent a tree structure and group data together in every layer.

For example your keys range from 0 to 1,000,000 then you will have in the first layer:

```
1) all keys from 0 to 99,000
2) from 100,000 to 199,999
3) ...
10) from 900,00 to 1,000,000
```

And so you go on to lower layers where you split the subgroups again. In the lowest layer you have a vector containing the actually available keys within this group. By having 3 such layers you can reduce the number of keys to go through by ~ 1/1000 times the original number. This will greatly reduce the look-up time for a certain key.

Comment: I'm afraid the keys aren't homologous on large scales.

Comment: Well, large scales are (let's suppose you introduce 3 layers each with 10 subgroups) for unsigned int_32t: UINT_MAX / 1000 = 4.294.967.
If the number of keys in intervals of this length is more or less the same you are fine.

If you have accumulations within smaller intervals I would advise you to figure out the boundaries of those intervals and take them as a 'starting' interval for the above procedure.

If you have to add keys during the run and you don't know any accumulations before you can make it dynamically changing the boundaries of containers so the number of keys in each is ~ equal.